# How to have KeyPressed to listen to multiple Objects at the same time?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Bomberman game, and I need to be able to have multiplayer. The users should be able to move their characters at the same time, but I do not know how to switch focus for the KeyPressed methods. Here are two of my classes: The Jframe Bomberman Class, and the Character class.

```
public class Bomberman extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener,
    KeyListener {

private JButton singleplayer, multiplayer, howtoplay, highscores, goBack;
public Map[] game;
private JLabel scoreLabel, armor;
private JComboBox numEnemies;
private Highscore highscore = new Highscore();
private int score, armorscore;


public Bomberman() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    Color red = new Color(178, 0, 0);
    getContentPane().setBackground(red);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setStartScreen();
    setVisible(true);
}


private void setHighScores() {

    Font subtitle = new Font("Myriad Pro", Font.PLAIN, 32);
    setSize(1000, 750);

    goBack = new JButton();
    goBack.setBounds(300, 620, 240, 70);
    goBack.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    goBack.setForeground(Color.RED);
    goBack.setFont(subtitle);
    goBack.setText("Return");
    goBack.addActionListener(this);
    add(goBack);

}

private void setSingleplayer(int numEnemies) {

    setSize(1000, 800);
    repaint();
    score = 0;
    randomMap(numEnemies, true);
    JLabel playerScore, armorCount;

    scoreLabel = new JLabel();
    scoreLabel.setBounds(125, 15, 60, 30);
    scoreLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    scoreLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    scoreLabel.setText(getScore());
    add(scoreLabel);

    armor = new JLabel();
    armor.setBounds(80, 40, 10, 30);
    armor.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    armor.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    armor.setText(String.valueOf(getArmorscore()));
    add(armor);

    playerScore = new JLabel();
    playerScore.setBounds(10, 15, 110, 30);
    playerScore.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    playerScore.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    playerScore.setText("Player Score:");
    add(playerScore);

    armorCount = new JLabel();
    armorCount.setBounds(10, 40, 70, 30);
    armorCount.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    armorCount.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    armorCount.setText("Armor: ");
    add(armorCount);

}

private void setMultiplayer(int numEnemies) {

    setSize(1000, 800);
    repaint();
    score = 0;
    JLabel playerScore, score, playerScore2, score2, playerScore3, score3, playerScore4, score4;

    if (numEnemies == 0) {

        score = new JLabel();
        score.setBounds(130, 5, 150, 40);
        score.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score.setText("bomber.getScore()");
        add(score);

        playerScore = new JLabel();
        playerScore.setBounds(10, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore.setText("Player Score:");
        add(playerScore);

        score2 = new JLabel();
        score2.setBounds(830, 5, 150, 40);
        score2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score2.setText("bomber2.getScore()");
        add(score2);

        playerScore2 = new JLabel();
        playerScore2.setBounds(700, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore2.setText("Player2 Score:");
        add(playerScore2);

        randomMap(2, false);
    } else if (numEnemies == 1) {
        score = new JLabel();
        score.setBounds(130, 5, 150, 40);
        score.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score.setText("bomber.getScore()");
        add(score);

        playerScore = new JLabel();
        playerScore.setBounds(10, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore.setText("Player Score:");
        add(playerScore);

        score2 = new JLabel();
        score2.setBounds(830, 5, 150, 40);
        score2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score2.setText("bomber2.getScore()");
        add(score2);

        playerScore2 = new JLabel();
        playerScore2.setBounds(700, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore2.setText("Player2 Score:");
        add(playerScore2);

        score3 = new JLabel();
        score3.setBounds(130, 720, 150, 40);
        score3.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score3.setText("bomber3.getScore()");
        add(score3);

        playerScore3 = new JLabel();
        playerScore3.setBounds(10, 720, 120, 40);
        playerScore3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore3.setText("Player3 Score:");
        add(playerScore3);

        randomMap(3, false);
    } else if (numEnemies == 2) {

        score = new JLabel();
        score.setBounds(130, 5, 150, 40);
        score.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score.setText("bomber.getScore()");
        add(score);

        playerScore = new JLabel();
        playerScore.setBounds(10, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore.setText("Player Score:");
        add(playerScore);

        score2 = new JLabel();
        score2.setBounds(830, 5, 150, 40);
        score2.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score2.setText("bomber2.getScore()");
        add(score2);

        playerScore2 = new JLabel();
        playerScore2.setBounds(700, 5, 120, 40);
        playerScore2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore2.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore2.setText("Player2 Score:");
        add(playerScore2);

        score3 = new JLabel();
        score3.setBounds(140, 720, 150, 40);
        score3.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score3.setText("bomber3.getScore()");
        add(score3);

        playerScore3 = new JLabel();
        playerScore3.setBounds(10, 720, 120, 40);
        playerScore3.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore3.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore3.setText("Player3 Score:");
        add(playerScore3);

        score4 = new JLabel();
        score4.setBounds(830, 720, 150, 40);
        score4.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        score4.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        score4.setText("bomber4.getScore()");
        add(score4);

        playerScore4 = new JLabel();
        playerScore4.setBounds(700, 720, 120, 40);
        playerScore4.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        playerScore4.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        playerScore4.setText("Player4 Score:");
        add(playerScore4);

        randomMap(4, false);
    }

}

private void setHowtoplay() {

    try {
        Font subtitle = new Font("Myriad Pro", Font.PLAIN, 32);

        goBack = new JButton();
        goBack.setBounds(300, 620, 240, 70);
        goBack.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        goBack.setForeground(Color.RED);
        goBack.setFont(subtitle);
        goBack.setText("Return");
        goBack.addActionListener(this);
        add(goBack);

        Image howtoplay;
        howtoplay = ImageIO.read(new File("src/pics/howtoplay.png"));
        ImageIcon setPic = new ImageIcon(howtoplay);
        JLabel putHowto = new JLabel();
        putHowto.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 600);
        putHowto.setIcon(setPic);
        add(putHowto);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

private void randomMap(int numEnemies, boolean isSingleplayer) {

    try {
        Image floor = ImageIO.read(new File("src/pics/floor.fw.png"));
        System.out.println("Loading Game with " + numEnemies + " bombers.");
        game = new Map[361];

        Point cornerTopLeft, cornerTopRight, cornerBotLeft, cornerBotRight, topLeftRight, topLeftBot, topRightLeft, topRightBot, botLeftTop, botLeftRight, botRightLeft, botRightTop;

        cornerTopLeft = new Point(160, 65);
        cornerTopRight = new Point(790, 65);
        cornerBotLeft = new Point(160, 695);
        cornerBotRight = new Point(790, 695);
        topLeftRight = new Point(195, 65);
        topLeftBot = new Point(160, 100);
        topRightLeft = new Point(755, 65);
        topRightBot = new Point(790, 100);
        botLeftTop = new Point(160, 660);
        botLeftRight = new Point(195, 695);
        botRightLeft = new Point(755, 695);
        botRightTop = new Point(790, 660);

        Random generator = new Random();
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
            boolean l = generator.nextBoolean();

            if ((i % 19) == 0) {
                k = k + 35;
                j = 0;
            } else {
                k = k + 0;
                if (i > 0) {
                    j = j + 35;
                }
            }

            Point o = new Point((160 + j), (30 + k));

            if (isSingleplayer == true) {
                if (numEnemies == 0 && i == 0) {
                    game[360] = new Character(true, this, "Player");
                    add(game[360]); 
                    game[0] = new CharacterAI(this, "Bot 1", 0);
                    add(game[0]);   
                    System.out.println("2 bombers called");
                } else if (numEnemies == 1 && i == 0) {
                    game[360] = new Character(true, this, "Player");
                    add(game[360]);     
                    game[0] = new CharacterAI(this, "Bot 1", 0);
                    add(game[0]);   
                    game[18] = new CharacterAI(this, "Bot 2", 18);
                    add(game[18]);      
                    System.out.println("3 bombers called");
                } else if (numEnemies == 2 && i == 0) {
                    game[360] = new Character(true, this,"Player");
                    add(game[360]); 
                    game[0] = new CharacterAI(this,"Bot 1", 0);
                    add(game[0]);   
                    game[18] = new CharacterAI(this, "Bot 2", 18);
                    add(game[18]);      
                    game[342] = new CharacterAI(this, "Bot 3", 342);
                    add(game[342]);     
                    System.out.println("4 bombers called");
                }
            } else {
                if (numEnemies == 2 && i == 0) {
                        game[0] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player1");
                        add(game[0]);
                        game[18] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player2");
                        add(game[18]);
                        System.out.println("2 bombers called");
                } else if (numEnemies == 3 && i == 0) {
                        game[0] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player1");
                        add(game[0]);
                        game[18] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player2");
                        add(game[18]);
                        game[342] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player3");
                        add(game[342]);
                        System.out.println("3 bombers called");
                } else if (numEnemies == 4 && i == 0) {
                        game[0] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player1");
                        add(game[0]);
                        game[18] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player2");
                        add(game[18]);
                        game[342] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player3");
                        add(game[342]);
                        game[360] = new Character(false, this,
                                "Player4");
                        add(game[360]);
                        System.out.println("4 bombers called");
                }
            }

            if (i > 18 && i < 38 || i > 56 && i < 76 || i > 94 && i < 114
                    || i > 133 && i < 152 || i > 170 && i < 190 || i > 208
                    && i < 228 || i > 246 && i < 266 || i > 284 && i < 304
                    || i > 322 && i < 342) {

                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    game[i] = new IndestructibleObject(160 + j, 30 + k);
                    add(game[i]);
                } else {

                    if (l == true
                            && DestroyableObject.getNumDestroyableObject() < 141
                            && !o.equals(cornerTopLeft)
                            && !o.equals(cornerTopRight)
                            && !o.equals(cornerBotRight)
                            && !o.equals(cornerBotLeft)
                            && !o.equals(topLeftRight)
                            && !o.equals(topLeftBot)
                            && !o.equals(topRightLeft)
                            && !o.equals(botLeftTop)
                            && !o.equals(topRightBot)
                            && !o.equals(botLeftRight)
                            && !o.equals(botRightLeft)
                            && !o.equals(botRightTop)) {

                        game[i] = new DestroyableObject(160 + j, 30 + k,
                                this);
                        add(game[i]);
                    } else {
                        game[i] = new Map(i + "", 0);
                        game[i].setBounds((160 + j), (30 + k), 35, 35);
                        game[i].setText("");
                        game[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(floor));
                        game[i].setOpaque(false);
                        add(game[i]);
                    }

                }
            } else {

                if (l == true
                        && DestroyableObject.getNumDestroyableObject() < 141
                        && !o.equals(cornerTopLeft)
                        && !o.equals(cornerTopRight)
                        && !o.equals(cornerBotRight)
                        && !o.equals(cornerBotLeft)
                        && !o.equals(topLeftRight) && !o.equals(topLeftBot)
                        && !o.equals(topRightLeft) && !o.equals(botLeftTop)
                        && !o.equals(topRightBot)
                        && !o.equals(botLeftRight)
                        && !o.equals(botRightLeft)
                        && !o.equals(botRightTop)) {

                    game[i] = new DestroyableObject(160 + j, 30 + k, this);
                    add(game[i]);
                } else {
                    game[i] = new Map(i + "", 0);
                    game[i].setBounds((160 + j), (30 + k), 35, 35);
                    game[i].setText("");
                    game[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(floor));
                    game[i].setOpaque(false);
                    add(game[i]);
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

public void increaseScore(int type) {
    if (type == 1) {
        score = score + 100;
        scoreLabel.setText(getScore());
    } else if (type == 2) {
        score = score + 50;
        scoreLabel.setText(getScore());
    } else if (type == 3) {
        score = score + 1000;
        scoreLabel.setText(getScore());
    }
}

public String getScore() {
    String strScore = String.valueOf(score);
    return strScore;
}

public int getArmorscore() {
    return armorscore;
}

public void setArmorscore(int armorscore) {
    this.armorscore = armorscore;
    armor.setText(String.valueOf(getArmorscore()));
}

public void gameEnd(boolean isSingleplayer) {

    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().revalidate();
    getContentPane().repaint();

    if (isSingleplayer == true) {

        DestroyableObject.reset();
        Font title = new Font("Myriad Pro", Font.PLAIN, 80);
        Font subtitle = new Font("Myriad Pro", Font.PLAIN, 26);

        setSize(1000, 750);
        JLabel gameOver = new JLabel();
        gameOver.setBounds(250, 50, 500, 70);
        gameOver.setFont(title);
        gameOver.setText("GAME OVER");
        gameOver.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(gameOver);

        JLabel score = new JLabel();
        score.setBounds(200, 250, 500, 70);
        score.setFont(subtitle);
        score.setText("Your Score: " + getScore());
        score.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(score);

        JButton subHighscore = new JButton();
        subHighscore.setBounds(180, 560, 260, 70);
        subHighscore.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        subHighscore.setForeground(Color.RED);
        subHighscore.setFont(subtitle);
        subHighscore.setText("Submit Highscore");
        subHighscore.addActionListener(this);
        add(subHighscore);

        goBack = new JButton();
        goBack.setBounds(500, 560, 240, 70);
        goBack.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        goBack.setForeground(Color.RED);
        goBack.setFont(subtitle);
        goBack.setText("Return");
        goBack.addActionListener(this);
        add(goBack);

    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == howtoplay) {

        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        setHowtoplay();

    } else if (e.getSource() == goBack) {

        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        setStartScreen();
    } else if (e.getSource() == highscores) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        setHighScores();
    } else if (e.getSource() == singleplayer) {

        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        String[] list = { "1", "2", "3" };
        numEnemies = new JComboBox(list);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numEnemies,
                "Select the number of opponents: ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        setSingleplayer(numEnemies.getSelectedIndex());
    } else if (e.getSource() == multiplayer) {

        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().revalidate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
        String[] list = { "2", "3", "4" };
        numEnemies = new JComboBox(list);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numEnemies,
                "Select the number of players: ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        setMultiplayer(numEnemies.getSelectedIndex());
    } else if (e.getSource() == game[360]) {
        if (game[360].getType() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Game over");
        }
    }

}
}
```

This is my Character class:

```
public class Character extends Map implements KeyListener {

private static int numCharacter = 0;
private int moveUp, moveDown, moveLeft, moveRight, placeBomb, moveSpeed,
        direction, source, armor;
public int maxBombs, numBombs;
private int bombExplodeTime, bombRange;
private Bomberman host;
private boolean isSingleplayer;
private Bomb bomb;

public Character(boolean ifSingleplayer, Bomberman game, String name) {

    super("Character", 3);
    host = game;
    this.setName(name);
    isSingleplayer = ifSingleplayer;
    maxBombs = 1;
    numBombs = 0;
    bombExplodeTime = 1000;
    bombRange = 0; 
    armor = 0;
    try {
        Image moveDownImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Down.fw.png"));
        if (ifSingleplayer == true){
            if (numCharacter == 0) {
                addKeyListener(this);
                setBounds(790, 695, 35, 35);
                setSource(360);
                moveUp = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
                moveDown = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;
                moveLeft = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
                moveRight = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
                placeBomb = KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
                setFocusable(true);
            }
            if (numCharacter == 1) {
                setBounds(160, 65, 35, 35);
                setSource(0);
            }
            if (numCharacter == 2) {
                setBounds(160, 695, 35, 35);
                setSource(18);
            }
            if (numCharacter == 3) {
                setBounds(790, 65, 35, 35);
                setSource(342);
            }

        }else{

        if (numCharacter == 0) {
            setBounds(160, 65, 35, 35);
            setSource(0);
            moveUp = KeyEvent.VK_W;
            moveDown = KeyEvent.VK_S;
            moveLeft = KeyEvent.VK_A;
            moveRight = KeyEvent.VK_D;
            placeBomb = KeyEvent.VK_C;
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(this);

        }

        if (numCharacter == 1) {
            setBounds(790, 65, 35, 35);
            setSource(18);
            moveUp = KeyEvent.VK_Y;
            moveDown = KeyEvent.VK_H;
            moveLeft = KeyEvent.VK_G;
            moveRight = KeyEvent.VK_J;
            placeBomb = KeyEvent.VK_M;
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(this);
        }

        if (numCharacter == 2) {
            setBounds(160, 695, 35, 35);
            setSource(342);
            moveUp = KeyEvent.VK_P;
            moveDown = KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON;
            moveLeft = KeyEvent.VK_L;
            moveRight = KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE;
            placeBomb = KeyEvent.VK_SLASH;
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(this);

        }
        if (numCharacter == 3) {
            setBounds(790, 695, 35, 35);
            setSource(360);
            moveUp = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
            moveDown = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;
            moveLeft = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
            moveRight = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
            placeBomb = KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL;
            setFocusable(true);
            addKeyListener(this);
        }
        }

        setOpaque(false);
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveDownImage));
        numCharacter++;

    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

public int getBombExplodeTime() {
    return bombExplodeTime;
}

public void setBombExplodeTime(int bombExplodeTime) {
    this.bombExplodeTime = bombExplodeTime;
}

public void checkEnd() {
    if (isSingleplayer == true && getNumCharacter() == 0) {
        host.gameEnd(isSingleplayer);
    } else if (isSingleplayer == false && getNumCharacter() == 1) {
        host.gameEnd(isSingleplayer);
    }
}

public int getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(int source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public void increaseMaxBombs(){
    maxBombs++;
}

public int getBombRange() {
    return bombRange;
}

public void setBombRange(int bombRange) {
    this.bombRange = bombRange;
}

public void runUp(int source) {
    // direction up = 1
    try {
        Image moveUpImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Up.fw.png"));
        switchButtons(source, source - 19);
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

public void runDown(int source) {
    // direction down = 2
    try {
        Image moveDownImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Down.fw.png"));
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveDownImage));
        switchButtons(source, source + 19);
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

public void runLeft(int source) {
    // direction left = 3
    try {
        Image moveLeftImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Left.fw.png"));
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveLeftImage));
        switchButtons(source, source - 1);
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

public void runRight(int source) {
    // direction right = 4
    try {
        Image moveRightImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Right.fw.png"));
        setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveRightImage));
        switchButtons(source, source + 1);
    } catch (IOException error) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }
}

public int getMoveSpeed() {
    return moveSpeed;
}

public void pickUpMoveSpeed() {
    moveSpeed++;
}

public int getArmor() {
    return armor;
}

public void pickUpArmor(int i) {
    armor = i;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public static int getNumCharacter() {
    return numCharacter;
}

public static void setNumCharacter(int numCharacter) {
    Character.numCharacter = numCharacter;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    /**
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_Y){
        System.out.println("#");
    host.game[18].requestFocus();
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){
        System.out.println("3");
    host.game[0].requestFocus();
    }
    **/
    try {
        Image moveRightImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Right.fw.png"));
        Image moveUpImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Up.fw.png"));
        Image moveDownImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Down.fw.png"));
        Image moveLeftImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "src/pics/Character-Left.fw.png"));

        if (key == moveLeft) {
            try {
                if (getDirection() != 3) {
                    setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveLeftImage));
                    setDirection(3);
                } else if (this.getY() == host.game[source - 1].getY()
                        && this.getX() - 35 == host.game[source - 1].getX()
                        && getDirection() == 3
                        && host.game[source - 1].getType() == 0) {
                        if (host.game[source - 1].getName() == "Destroyed" || 
                            host.game[source - 1].getName() == "IncreaseRange" ||
                            host.game[source - 1].getName() == "IncreaseSpeed" ||
                            host.game[source - 1].getName() == "IncreaseArmor" ||
                            host.game[source - 1].getName() == "IncreaseBomb" ||
                            host.game[source - 1].getName() == "IncreaseExplodeSpeed") {                            
                            if (((DestroyableObject) host.game[source - 1]).getIsPowerup() == true) {
                                ((DestroyableObject) host.game[source - 1]).toGrass(source-1, this);
                                runLeft(source);
                                source = source - 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                runLeft(source);
                                source = source - 1;
                            }
                    } 
                    else {
                        runLeft(source);
                        source = source - 1;
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException f) {
                System.out.println("I can't move there");
            }
        }

        if (key == moveRight) {
            try {
                if (getDirection() != 4) {
                    setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveRightImage));
                    setDirection(4);
                } else if (this.getY() == host.game[source + 1].getY()
                        && this.getX() + 35 == host.game[source + 1].getX()
                        && getDirection() == 4
                        && host.game[source + 1].getType() == 0) {
                    if (host.game[source + 1].getName() == "Destroyed" || 
                        host.game[source + 1].getName() == "IncreaseRange" ||
                        host.game[source + 1].getName() == "IncreaseSpeed" ||
                        host.game[source + 1].getName() == "IncreaseArmor" ||
                        host.game[source + 1].getName() == "IncreaseBomb" ||
                        host.game[source + 1].getName() == "IncreaseExplodeSpeed") {                            
                        if (((DestroyableObject) host.game[source + 1]).getIsPowerup() == true) {
                            ((DestroyableObject) host.game[source + 1]).toGrass(source+1, this);
                            runRight(source);
                            source = source + 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            runRight(source);
                            source = source + 1;
                        }
                } 
                else {
                    runRight(source);
                    source = source + 1;
                }

                }
            } catch (NullPointerException f) {
                System.out.println("I can't move there");
            }
        }

        if (key == moveUp) {
            try {
                if (getDirection() != 1) {
                    setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveUpImage));
                    setDirection(1);
                } else if (this.getY() - 35 == host.game[source - 19]
                        .getY()
                        && this.getX() == host.game[source - 19].getX()
                        && getDirection() == 1
                        && host.game[source - 19].getType() == 0) {
                    if (host.game[source - 19].getName() == "Destroyed" || 
                        host.game[source - 19].getName() == "IncreaseRange" ||
                        host.game[source - 19].getName() == "IncreaseSpeed" ||
                        host.game[source - 19].getName() == "IncreaseArmor" ||
                        host.game[source - 19].getName() == "IncreaseBomb" ||
                        host.game[source - 19].getName() == "IncreaseExplodeSpeed") {                           
                        if (((DestroyableObject) host.game[source - 19]).getIsPowerup() == true) {
                            ((DestroyableObject) host.game[source - 19]).toGrass(source-19, this);
                            runUp(source);
                            source = source - 19;
                        }
                        else {
                            runUp(source);
                            source = source - 19;
                        }
                } 
                else {
                    runUp(source);
                    source = source - 19;
                }

                }
            } catch (NullPointerException f) {
                System.out.println("I can't move there");
            }
        }

        if (key == moveDown) {
            try {
                if (getDirection() != 2) {
                    setIcon(new ImageIcon(moveDownImage));
                    setDirection(2);
                } else if (this.getY() + 35 == host.game[source + 19]
                        .getY()
                        && this.getX() == host.game[source + 19].getX()
                        && getDirection() == 2
                        && host.game[source + 19].getType() == 0) {if (host.game[source + 19].getName() == "Destroyed" || 
                        host.game[source + 19].getName() == "IncreaseRange" ||
                        host.game[source + 19].getName() == "IncreaseSpeed" ||
                        host.game[source + 19].getName() == "IncreaseArmor" ||
                        host.game[source + 19].getName() == "IncreaseBomb" ||
                        host.game[source + 19].getName() == "IncreaseExplodeSpeed") {                           
                        if (((DestroyableObject) host.game[source + 19]).getIsPowerup() == true) {
                            ((DestroyableObject) host.game[source + 19]).toGrass(source+19, this);
                            runDown(source);
                            source = source + 19;
                        }
                        else {
                            runDown(source);
                            source = source + 19;
                        }
                } 
                else {
                    runDown(source);
                    source = source + 19;
                }
            }
            } catch (NullPointerException f) {
                System.out.println("I can't move there");
            }
        }

        if (key == placeBomb) {
            bomb = new Bomb(this.getX(), this.getY(), getDirection(),
                    source, this, host, bombExplodeTime, bombRange);
            add(bomb);
        }

    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException f) {
        System.out.println("I can't move there");

    } catch (IOException g) {
        System.out.println("Error, problem reading image");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void switchButtons(int one, int two) {

    Rectangle temp = this.getBounds();
    this.setBounds(host.game[two].getBounds());
    host.game[two].setBounds(temp);

    Map tempOne = host.game[two];
    host.game[two] = this;
    host.game[one] = tempOne;

}

public int getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(int direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
}

public Bomberman getHost() {
    return host;
}
}
```

Comment: You have given us _a lot_ of code. Rather than asking people to wade through hundreds of lines of source, consider cutting down your question to the bare essentials. I'd rather see even a prose description of the problem rather than the huge amount of code you've given.

Comment: Basic answer.  Don't.  Instead of using `KeyListener`, try using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allows to define the level of focus a component needs before a key event is triggered